# europass db structure relational or noSql

Tags: database, laravel, mongodb, orm, relational-database

I need to design a relationa db for storing europass format cv thats student should fill in a form in my site.

So i split it in 5 tables:
[image: db structure]

Studend contains all the personal informations such age, sex, phone number etc. used even in other parts of the app, even in relation with user's table that store password and login infos;

> Cvs

is tha main table of the Europass and contains all the "single data" of an  europass cv: job position loking for, professional goal, digital skills (as list), comunication skills etc.

> Training

contains all the experience made by him on school or professional formation;

> languages

contains each language and level for speaking and write prods etc;

> workingExperinces

contains each working experience with some descriptions etc

its a good option menage a big wide relations like this one or is better to convert all in a mongo db structure for example?
I need to use it as Eloquent model too...im in a Laravel app!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

records size is not the main point when choosing between a SQL or a NoSQL solution. it depends on the structure of your records and actions that you perform on that data . Try to answer these questions:

- Does every record on my table have a fixed number of attributes? ( yes ? rel : noSQL )
- Does an attribute has always the same type of value on every record? ( yes ? rel : noSQL )
- Do I usually use my data for reading ? ( no ? rel : noSQL )
- Am I going to extract statistics from this data? ( no ? rel : noSQL )
- Is my data structured like a network/graph or as a hierarchy ( no ? rel : noSQL )

if you think that NoSQL is a better solution for your case, there is a  [package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) based on Eloquent for mongoDB!